# Looking for an explanation of why `[1,2,3] === [1,2,3]` is false in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I was looking at clause 11.9.6 of ES5 trying to figure out why [1,2,3] === [1,2,3] returns false.

The code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
a === b // false
```

Relevant rules for the strict equality comparison algo:

> x === y
>
> (1) If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return **false**.
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> (7) Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise return **false**.

Any ideas why an interpreter returns false?

Comment: 'Return true if x and y refer to the same object.' You just made two objects and compared them, isn't this the expected behaviour?

Comment: I didn't realize they were two separate objects. Do they both not refer to to the Array object?

Comment: the Array is a type not an object.

Comment: Two different instances of the array _type_. Here the misunderstanding is between objects and types, I guess, it could be made slightly clearer by 'the same instance'.

Comment: The *instances* of Array are different, even though they are initialized with the same values. If you change a, b is not altered, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` and `b` are two different objects, they just happen to have the same Number values in them.  If you did `a[0] = 42;` then `b[0]` would still equal 1.

Comment: Just a small correction. The arrays *don't* have the same elements in them. Elements are properties, and one property cannot belong to two different objects. (Also, the term "same elements" is not useful since properties cannot be compared - only their values can.) A better way of putting it would be to say that "they just happen to have the same *Number* values in them".

Comment: Agreed, that is more precise.  It's that kind of ambiguity in wording that causes confusion in the first place.  Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

They do not refer to the same object. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `a` and `b` refer to different objects. They might each contain the same value and are instances of the same class, but you can change one and the other stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

`(7) Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise return false.` -they doesn't refer to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are two objects created.